# Copy snapshot files from Publisher, Paste and Apply on subscriber in SQL Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I read an excellent article about copying the snapshot files for Transactional replication from Publisher to Subscriber and Apply them on subscriber.

[Link](https://repltalk.com/2010/03/07/tips-to-improve-performance-when-applying-snapshot-in-transactional-replication/)

But the focus of this article is directed to Transactional Replication.

I want to know how we can copy the snapshots from publisher, paste them on the subscriber and apply them on subscriber. I am using Merge Replication with push subscriber, Distributor and Publisher are on the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - With Merge we can copy the snapshot files to the Subscriber and apply the snapshot locally using the [Merge Agent **-AltSnapshotFolder** parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147839.aspx).